# Distribute nodes evenly over qgraphicsscene

Tags: qt, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4, networkx

Hi I am trying to create a force directed graph using qt/pyqt. I am taking inspiration from
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I have a qgraphicsscene and I my first step is to distribute the primary nodes evenly over the scene, step 2 is to go through each primary node and add links. The data is in a sqlite table. There is nothing complicated about getting the data and adding nodes onto the scene. It is drawing it on the scene correctly that I am struggling with.
My first question: how best to evenly distribute x nodes over a qgraphicsscene that is say 400 x 400. I would like to avoid nodes clustering in a part of the scene.
My second question: are there any libraries that I can use to create such graphs?
*Note: I am trying to create an interactive graph, so that a user can right-click and call additional functions, drag nodes about etc*
I have heard of NetworkX but to the best of my knowledge its for generating static images.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to distribute nodes based on links between them? Distributing nodes without considering links is trivial.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, I would need to consider the links between the nodes as well. Like in the links above the movement of the nodes affects their links and effectively the scene. If there are any pointers in how I can achieve what mbostock has done in javascript, in qt/pyqt I would really appreciate it.